# Multiple Outlets on one page

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to put together an application using Ember.js

Find the jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/wprk14/ARbMa/

I think I have the routing / pages / templates working but I can't get my navigation to show up. I think I need to add another outlet for navigation but the documentation isn't really helping me understand what I need to do.

Relevant HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="main-content">
        <script type="text/x-handlebars">
            {{outlet}}
        </script>
    </div>
</div>
<footer>
    {{outlet nav}}
</footer>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="nav">
    <ul id="tab-bar">
        <li>{{#linkTo "messages.inbound"}}Inbox{{/linkTo}}</li>
        <li>{{#linkTo "messages.outbound"}}Sentbox{{/linkTo}}</li>
        <li>{{#linkTo "parking"}}Parking{{/linkTo}}</li>
        <li>{{#linkTo "fuel"}}Fuel Tracker{{/linkTo}}</li>
    </ul>
</script>
```

Relevant JS

```
App.Router.map(function() {
this.route("login");
this.resource('messages', function() {
    this.route('inbound');
    this.route('outbound');
});
this.route("parking");
this.route("fuel", { path: '/fuel-tracker' });
});
```

Comment: After I had implemented the solution (and done some other work). My code was this: http://jsfiddle.net/FNn4R/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add {{render nav}} instead of {{outlet nav}} to render the navigation bar on all the pages, regardless of what is inside the current outlet.

Comment: sure thing, you can also pass data into it as well.  For example I have an event template and inside of it, I want to render a chat template, so I can do {{render chat chats}} and it passes in the model's chats array.   My model is event, and the array is event.chats.